# Laravel 5.1 oAuth 2 server 'invalid scope' error

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, laravel-5, restful-authentication

I'm using [oauth2-server-laravel](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel) for my API. I want to give scopes to clients app who are using my API (Android, Windows,IOS and web). Therefore I implemented following way.

my table data as follows

**oauth_clients** Table

> +-----------+---------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
>   | id| secret  | name    | created_at          | updated_at          |
>   +-----------+---------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
>   | 123456789 | secret1 | web     | 2015-08-10 00:00:00 | 2015-08-10 00:00:00 |
>   | 234567890 | secret2 | win_app | 2015-08-10 00:00:00 | 2015-08-10 00:00:00 |
>   +-----------+---------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+

**oauth_scopes** Table

> +--------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
>   | id     | description        | created_at          | updated_at          |
>   +--------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
>   | scope1 | guest level access | 2015-08-10 00:00:00 | 2015-08-10 00:00:00 |
>   | scope2 | admin level access | 2015-08-10 00:00:00 | 2015-08-10 00:00:00 |
>   +--------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+

**oauth_client_scopes** Table

> +----+-----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
>   | id | client_id | scope_id | created_at          | updated_at          |
>   +----+-----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
>   |  1 | 234567890 | scope2   | 2015-08-10 00:00:00 | 2015-08-10 00:00:00 |
>   |  2 | 123456789 | scope1   | 2015-08-10 00:00:00 | 2015-08-10 00:00:00 |
>   +----+-----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+

My **routes.php**,

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'oauth:scope2','prefix' => 'api/v1'], function () {
           Route::GET('categoriesWithOffers', 'api\v1\CategoriesController@categoriesWithOffers');  
});
```

and my **oauth2.php** settings as below

```
'grant_types' => [
    'client_credentials' => [
        'class' => '\League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\ClientCredentialsGrant',
        'access_token_ttl' => 3600
    ],
],
'token_type' => 'League\OAuth2\Server\TokenType\Bearer',
'state_param' => false,
'scope_param' => false,
'scope_delimiter' => ',',
'default_scope' => null,
'limit_clients_to_grants' => false,
'limit_clients_to_scopes' => false,
'limit_scopes_to_grants' => false,
'http_headers_only' => false,
```

I requested following way

```
http://domain.com/api/v1/categoriesWithOffers?access token=Jo7lAqE2uD3KbyLQWlrmukzyHJOQBHZ1QFsuBKUt&scope=scope1
```

and it gives me this error

> {
>     "error": "invalid_scope",
>     "error_description": "The requested scope is invalid, unknown, or malformed. Check the \"scope2\" scope."
>   }

When I added current request token and scope to the 
**oauth_access_token_scopes** table it works fine.But I need to define scopes as mentioned at the bigining of this question.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: also I have tried  'limit_clients_to_scopes' => true, and  'default_scope' => 'scope2',

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope is used when making requests to get the access token

```
/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=234567890&client_secret=123456789&scope=scope1
```

With this url then you will get the access token which you can then use on your urls.